# What does MM stand for in git show --raw output for merge commits?

Tags: git, merge, commit, show

I'm looking at output of `git show --numstat --shortstat --raw --pretty=medium -p` command and see that for merge commits output differs. This is what I'm getting:

```
commit cec68e2b00d86357c18b576cbaed52cc1ea42a74
Merge: b2ea79c e4900df
Author: jeresig <jeresig@gmail.com>
Date:   Thu Dec 9 12:44:30 2010 -0500

    Merge branch 'bug5566' of https://github.com/csnover/jquery into csnover-bug5566

16      16      src/manipulation.js
76      56      test/unit/manipulation.js
::100644 100644 100644 e09dd7e... c592b7a... 8d951b6... MM      src/manipulation.js
::100644 100644 100644 4805016... 8ee3688... 23ed898... MM      test/unit/manipulation.js
```

Why there's no diff information and what does `MM` stand for? I haven't seen this modifier before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no diff information because `--raw` suppresses that output.  (Admittedly this is non-obvious from the documentation.)

The "raw" output is documented in the `git diff-tree` man page, in the sections [Raw Output Format](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-diff-tree.html#_raw_output_format) and [diff Format for Merges](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-diff-tree.html#_diff_format_for_merges).  There are two `M`s in your example because it's a merge commit with two parents.  To look at this example in more detail:

```
::100644 100644 100644 e09dd7e... c592b7a... 8d951b6... MM src/manipulation.js
```

... the three file modes (`100644 100644 100644`) give you the file mode in the first parent, the second parent and this commit.  Similarly, the next three fields (`e09dd7e... c592b7a... 8d951b6..`) give you the [object names](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitglossary.html#def_object_name) of the blob that represents that file's content in the first parent, the second parent and the merge commit.  The `MM` is then two "score" fields, telling you that this file was modified with respect to parent 1 and also modified with respect to parent 2.